# Creating a DEM from PDF?

Tags: dem, pdf

sorry if this is a simple question, but based on my search terms I keep getting PDF papers about DEMs. Someone has asked me to generate fill quantities off of their lidar data which they have presented to me as a PDF. I'm under the assumption that a  PDF is treated as a flat image and can not produce elevation information to a GIS program - but am I wrong? I converted the PDF to a .tiff composed of 4 bands 0-255 which screams RGB to me....

Comment: A PDF can be vector data (or a mix of vector and raster or only raster) and pdf vector object may have attribute. That being said it seem unlikely that a pdf is being used to carry lidar data in a usable way, are you sure that it's not just a way to easily visualize the data  without specific software and that the data are not available in a more conventional format ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by a "flat image" but rasters in PDF (or GeoPDF) are not data but rather just a backdrop picture in a JPEG format. I believe that in a GeoPDF format, the vectors can be retained as actual data, just not rasters. The entire PDF can be converted to a raster image (for use in software such as ESRI collector) but only in regard to it being a georeferenced picture and not in containing data (eg., elevation).

Unless it is exported as a greyscale image, TIFF's will always be a 3 (RGB) or 4 (CMYK) band composite in a 8 or 16 bit depth. In contrast, a DEM is a single band, often floating point, raster where the values represent elevation values and not RGB or CMYK color values. When you convert a PDF or GeoPDF to a tiff it is no different than a picture of your house, excepting that with a GeoPDF the resulting tiff is georeferenced.